# Is there a way to check if a page has been landed on from an external source

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using c#, I m looking to personalise a page if its the first page the user has come across.

I'm not concerned whether the solution is bulletproof because the feature is purely asthetical and can degrade.

It must use be an ASP.NET method, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with

[Request.UrlReferrer.Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

you can get the URL of the client's previous request. But this won't work with https from external pages

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use this

[Url referel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx)

This property contains previous page url, so you can check if current request is from your site.